# Having Trouble Displaying Input Value in Ordered List

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, atom-editor

I'm having trouble making a button that will put text inputted from a box to a list element that is inside an ordered list. My professor asked that I only use createElement, textContent and appendChild (also can't use jQuery), so my options to move the text from the input to li are extremely limited. Here's what I have so far:

```
let main = function() {

  if (this.id == "btn1") {
    let listDiv = document.getElementById('div');
    let olCreator = document.createElement('OL');
    div.appendChild(olCreator).setAttribute("id", "ol");
  }

if (this.id == "btn2") {
  let olGrab = document.getElementById('OL');
  let liCreator = document.createElement('LI');
  ol.appendChild(liCreator);
  let inputText = document.getElementById("inputBox").textContent;
  let liDone = document.getElementById('li').appendChild(inputText);
}
};
```

I'm pretty sure I don't want to give the li element an id, because if I do, the inputted text will go into every li element, and that'd be bad. As of now, the console tells me this when I press the button in my HTML document:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
>   at HTMLButtonElement.main

Answer (score 0):

You are calling appendChild on elements that do not exist or have value null.

Instead of

```
div.appendChild(olCreator).setAttribute("id", "ol");
```

try

```
lastDiv.appendChild(olCreator).setAttribute("id", "ol");
```

Same in the second condition, change **ol.appendChild** to **olGrab.appendChild**